# Don't really understand the absorption law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I don't really get the absorption law, specifically in this case:

$$ (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor q) \equiv  (\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) \lor (q \land q) $$

The absorption law is used here: $ (\lnot p \land q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) $

I don't really understand the use of absorption law in this case, and if someone could explain it to me on a similar example or something, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, "the absorption law is used here"? Do you mean that it is used to change $ (\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) \lor (q \land q) $ into $ (\lnot p \land q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) $
?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean that it is used here: $ (\lnot p \land q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) $

When we use the absorption law, it cancels out, but I don't get it how? So in the end we only get: $ \lnot p \land \lnot r \lor q $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With :

> $(¬p∧¬r)∨(¬p∧q)∨(q∧¬r)∨(q∧q)$

you first apply $(q \land q) \equiv q$ to simplify it :

> $(¬p∧¬r)∨(¬p∧q)∨(q∧¬r)∨q$.

Consider now : $(q∧¬r)∨q$; applying [Absorption Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Logic)) : $p∨(p∧q) \equiv p$, we have that it is equivalent to $q$.

Thus :

> $[(¬p∧¬r)∨(¬p∧q)]∨[(q∧¬r)∨q] \equiv (¬p∧¬r)∨(¬p∧q)∨q$.

Apply it again to : $(¬p∧q)∨q$, which is again equivalent to $q$, to get :

> > $(¬p∧¬r)∨[(¬p∧q)∨q] \equiv (¬p∧¬r)∨q$.

---

Regarding *absorption* :

> > $p∨(p∧q) \equiv p$

you can prove it with *Natural Deduction* or verify it via truth table :

- if $p$ is TRUE, then $p \lor (p \land q)$ is TRUE, by truth table for $\lor$;
- if $p$ is FALSE, then $(p \land q)$ is FALSE, by truth table for $\land$; so both $p$ and $(p \land q)$ are FALSE, and thus $p∨(p∧q)$ is FALSE, by truth table for $\lor$.

Comment: Wow, that clears things up. We were doing this example in college and for some reason we always skip a few steps. I thought we somehow only used the absorption law once, so I really didn't get it. Thank you very much for the explanation, I really appreciate it.